# Maven: Enforce that a classpath resource exists at runtime

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-enforcer-plugin

I would like to enforce the existence of certain resources in the runtime classpath with Maven.

Any recommendations how to achieve that?

Thanks and kind regards

Oliver

Edit: Obviously my question is not precise enough. I would like to ensure a style.css file is located in the root of the runtime classpath. I do not care about how this resource found its way into the classpath. I just want to ensure the resource is present in the runtime classpath.

Comment: With runtime you mean the runtime of your application?

Comment: Yes, exactly... the maven runtime scope.

Comment: You can't check at buildtime what's on the classpath during runtime ...This can be done in your application code as.a pre check before your application starts...

Comment: I would like to solve it using a maven plugin like the duplicate-finder-maven-plugin which ensures that there are no duplicates in the classpath.

Comment: If you correctly put your `style.css` into `src/main/resources` it will be copied into the correct location.

Comment: I don't understand the real problem?

Comment: I have an application jar which is executable. Moreover there are multiple other maven modules (jars) which contain a style.css file. We use there modules for delivering different tyles/brandings to different customers.

I just want to ensure that there is exactly one style.css in the classapth of the application. With the duplicate-finder-maven-plugin I can ensure tht there is not more than one sytle.css, but additionally I would like to ensure that there is exactly one present.

The jar file including the style.css in included via a runtime dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219178/discussion-between-oliver-and-khmarbaise).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your path like that in your pom file

```
  <build>
    <resources>
       <resource>
          <directory>src/main/config</directory>  //this 
       </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/config</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
     </build>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add scope in your dependancy
like that

```
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>${log4j.version}</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

Comment: That does not refer to the question. I know how to add runtime dependencies. I want to ensure that a certain resource is avaialable in the classpath at the application's runtime.

Comment: @Oliver, could you be more precise what you want? What kind of application is this? A war run on JBoss? A standalone jar? For a war, a `runtime` dependency will automatically be available at runtime.

Comment: It's a Spring Boot app and I do NOT refer do dependencies but to certain classpath resources.